# Change value on event oninput typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, events

I have a span that I want to change in according to a value from an input on the event oninput

Here is my html :

```
  <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange" step="3" class="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        <p>Gain de temps: <span id="time"></span></p>
      </div>
```

My typescript file :

```
 var slider = document.getElementById("myRange") as HTMLInputElement;
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;

    var convertSlider = parseInt(slider.value); 
    var gainTime = Math.round(convertSlider * 4* (1 - Math.min(convertSlider, 200) * 40 / 10000)).toString();
    var gainTimeOutput = document.getElementById("time");
    gainTimeOutput.innerHTML = gainTime; 

    slider.oninput = e => {
      output.innerHTML = ((<HTMLTextAreaElement>e.target).value);
      gainTimeOutput.innerHTML = gainTime;
    };
```

With this solution, I have the value in my span `#time` but it doesn't change when I move the value of the slider, how to catch the event to also make change the value of my span `#time` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to do with this code: `output.innerHTML = ((<HTMLTextAreaElement>e.target).value);` But to accomplish what you described the assignment should rather be to the value of the slider.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
var gainTimeOutput = document.getElementById("time");

slider.oninput = e => {
  output.innerHTML = slider.value;
  
  var convertSlider = parseInt(slider.value); 
  var gainTime = Math.round(convertSlider * 4* (1 - Math.min(convertSlider, 200) * 40 / 10000)).toString();
  gainTimeOutput.innerHTML = gainTime; 
};
```

```html
  <div class="slidecontainer">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="50" class="slider myRange" id="myRange" step="3">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
    <p>Gain de temps: <span id="time"></span></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to put onChange attribute to your input, so it can change its value

something like:

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="50" onChange="handleInputChange()" class="slider" id="myRange" step="3" class="myRange" />
```

and in your script, put your code into a function

```
funtion handleInputChange() {
   console.log("hello")
   // your logic
}
```